# Find Horizontal Shear

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

We have a triangle that has vertices

$
A=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] 
\\
B=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 9\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] 
\\
C=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 3\\
 5\\
\end{array} \right] 
$

We transform triangle $ABC$ using the OX-shear transformation with $n = 2$.

**1 way**

$$
A'=\left[ \begin{array}{l}
 1&  2\\
 0&  1\\
\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] =\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 7\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] \,\,  B'=\left[ \begin{array}{l}
 1&  2\\
 0&  1\\
\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
 9\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] =\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 13\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] \,\, C'=\left[ \begin{array}{l}
 1&  2\\
 0&  1\\
\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
 3\\
 5\\
\end{array} \right] =\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 13\\
 5\\
\end{array} \right] 
$$

**2 way**

Return the triagle ABC to orgin (0,0). New vertex triangle:
$$
A_1=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] -\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] =\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 0\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right] \,\,  B_1=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 9\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] -\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] =\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 6\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right] \,\, C_1=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 3\\
 5\\
\end{array} \right] -\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] =\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 0\\
 3\\
\end{array} \right] 
$$

OX-shear transformation with $n = 2$.

$$
A'=\left[ \begin{array}{l}
 1&  2\\
 0&  1\\
\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
 0\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right] =\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 0\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right] \,\, B'=\left[ \begin{array}{l}
 1&  2\\
 0&  1\\
\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
 6\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right] =\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 6\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right] \,\, C'=\left[ \begin{array}{l}
 1&  2\\
 0&  1\\
\end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
 0\\
 3\\
\end{array} \right] =\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 6\\
 3\\
\end{array} \right] 
$$

*return to previous position triangle*

$$
A_2=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 0\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right] +\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] =\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] \,\, B_2=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 6\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right] +\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] =\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 9\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] \,\, C_2=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 6\\
 3\\
\end{array} \right] +\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 3\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right] =\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 9\\
 5\\
\end{array} \right] 
$$

We obtained two different image coordinates of the vertices of this triangle. What is the reason for this difference? Or the two ways given are also incorrect. Then how to correctly determine the image of this triangle?

Comment: Your first shear leaves points $\left[\begin{array}{c} x\\ 0\\ \end{array}\right]$ unchanged.  Your second shear leaves points $\left[\begin{array}{c} x\\ 2\\ \end{array}\right]$ unchanged.

Comment: 2 way step 3 we need add $\left[\begin{array}{ll}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}3 \\ 2\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{l}7 \\ 2\end{array}\right]$ ?

Comment: A shear has a given fixed line and a magnitude.  Your two examples have the same magnitude but different (though parallel) fixed lines.  If "OX-shear" means the chosen fixed line is the $x$-axis through the origin then your first example is correct and your second is wrong.